# Unable to push ruby on rails master project to heroku windows 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I have a problem whenever I do `git push heroku master`, it gives me the following error:

```
!Invalid path! 
Syntax is: git@heroku.com<app>.git where <app> is your app's name
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I have used MSysGit and I created a ruby on rails project, pushed it to github. 
then in the project folder I did `heroku login`, succesfully authenticated. Did `heroku create` sucessfully, created a RSA keypair, added it to heroku. then I try to push to heroku and it fails everytime, anyone able to help?

Comment: What is the output of `git remote -v`?

Comment: heroku  git@heroku.com:<app>.git <fetch>
heroku  git@heroku.com:<app>.git <push>

Comment: To be clear, it doesn't literally say `<app>`, does it? You've got a Heroku app name there, something like `unlimited-destiny-1282`? (Feel free to keep the actual URL private.)

Comment: no it does say my actual app name

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your SSH key being used is NOT yet uploaded to Heroku. I'm not familiar with your Git client, but what you need to do is find your SSH key file, then run:

`heroku keys:add /path/to/my/key.pub`

This will upload your public SSH key to Heroku, allowing you to push your repository.

Comment: I did heroku keys:add 
and says Found the following SSH public keys: 
1) github_rsa.pub
2) id_rsa.pub
I have selected nr 2 and then I try to push and still says invalid path